# eclipse rcp updates

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

For eclipse rcp applications, if we want to add a new feature and that needs to  be installed through update manager, dont we need to create update site?

Request to clarify my following doubts.

1. check for update means from where does the eclipse know that update is available? Is it from feature project? Feature project is creating new features to applicaton right?

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application

http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/p2_updates_tutorial/

These two examples show check for updates and install new software. what is here check for updates and Install new software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for updates checks all known update sites for new versions of plugins and features, which are **already installed** in your application. With Install new software you can install new plugins (and specify new update sites).

Comment: ok. thanks for the reply. For example I have one update site having one feature. That feature I have already installed through install new software.If I add second new feature to the update site, will it give the information like Update is found?

Comment: No, not for the second feature (because in fact it isn't an update for the installed plugins).